# Requests html page differs from browser

Tags: python, python-requests

So when I go to a page with python requests, it is rendering a different page. Obviously that is some script doing this. Is there any way to get the requests in python to render the same page so I can scrape it? I am really just starting to learn BeautifulSoup all over again.

[Page I want to scrape](https://www.yellowpages.com/new-orleans-la/mip/upperline-restaurant-526381149?lid=1001797484770)

```
page = requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.com/new-orleans-la/mip/upperline-restaurant-526381149?lid=1001797484770')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
# I am trying to find this class 'sales-info' but it isn't in the html when rendered.
business_name = soup.find('div', class_='sale-info')
print(business_name)
```

Comment: You've mistyped `sale-info`. It should be `sales-info`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like just a small type-o, `sale-info` should be `sales-info` (note the second **s**) try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.com/new-orleans-la/mip/upperline-restaurant-526381149?lid=1001797484770')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
# I am trying to find this class 'sales-info' but it isn't in the html when rendered.
business_name = soup.find('div', class_='sales-info')
print(business_name)
```

results:

```
<div class="sales-info"><h1>Upperline Restaurant</h1></div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the response. I did see the typo and am now scraping the info correctly.